# Swift Sort Dictionary by property of an object value

Tags: ios, swift, swift-dictionary

I have a dictionary like `<String,Loto>` and Loto is object like below;

```
Loto:   
 {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
    "oid": "64kbbqi8dbxygb00",
    "hafta": 961,
    "buyukIkramiyeKazananIl": "",
    "cekilisTarihi": "11/04/2015",
    "cekilisTuru": "SAYISAL_LOTO",
    "rakamlar": "03#02#48#16#15#08",
    "rakamlarNumaraSirasi": "02 - 03 - 08 - 15 - 16 - 48",
    "devretti": false,
    "devirSayisi": 0,
    "bilenKisiler": [
    {
    "oid": "64kbbxi8dbxyg403",
    "kisiBasinaDusenIkramiye": 7.35,
    "kisiSayisi": 185712,
    "tur": "$3_BILEN"
    },
    {
    "oid": "64kbbxi8dbxyg402",
    "kisiBasinaDusenIkramiye": 53.05,
    "kisiSayisi": 9146,
    "tur": "$4_BILEN"
    },
    {
    "oid": "64kbbxi8dbxyg401",
    "kisiBasinaDusenIkramiye": 4532.2,
    "kisiSayisi": 142,
    "tur": "$5_BILEN"
    },
    {
    "oid": "64kbbxi8dbxyg400",
    "kisiBasinaDusenIkramiye": 1528438.75,
    "kisiSayisi": 1,
    "tur": "$6_BILEN"
    }
    ],
    "buyukIkrKazananIlIlceler": [
    {
    "il": "10",
    "ilView": "BALIKESÄ°R",
    "ilce": "01001",
    "ilceView": "AYVALIK"
    }
    ],
    "kibrisHasilati": 51127,
    "devirTutari": 0.09,
    "kolonSayisi": 10537872,
    "kdv": 1599672.97,
    "toplamHasilat": 10537872,
    "hasilat": 8938199.03,
    "sov": 893819.9,
    "ikramiyeEH": 8044379.129999999,
    "buyukIkramiye": 1528432.03,
    "haftayaDevredenTutar": 0
    }
    }
```

So my dictionary like <"11042015",Loto> and i want to sort this dictionary by "hafta" property of loto object.

How can i do this? Please help me!

Comment: Is this the whole data or sample ?

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered, however you could could have a look at this tutorial on creating your own ordered dictionary: http://timekl.com/blog/2014/06/02/learning-swift-ordered-dictionaries/

Comment: @malav-soni this is sample data. My dictionary have 964 element like <"11042015",Loto>. So key is a string value is loto object. And i want to sort bye "hafta" property ob Loto object.

Comment: @abakersmith thanks for shared link, i'll try as soon as possible. May be hash keys help me.

Answer (score 10):

If `Loto` is an object with a `hafta` property, you can sort your dictionary by passing it into the `sorted` function, along with a closure that tells it how to order the entries:

```
sorted(dict) { $0.1.hafta < $1.1.hafta }
```

(`$0.1` and `$1.1` because dictionaries present as a sequence of key/value pairs - you want to sort by a property of the value i.e. tuple entry `1`)

Note, this will give you back a sorted array, of type `[(String,Loto)]` pairs, rather than a dictionary (as Swift dictionaries are unordered).

(if `Loto` is not really an object but rather another dictionary, you might need to do `{$0.1["hafta"] < $1.1["hafta"]}` - it really depends on how you’re holding your data - the good news is you don’t need to worry about optionals, since they can be compared with `<`)

If you don’t need the keys, just sort the values:

```
sorted(dict.values) { $0.hafta < $1.hafta }
```

which will give you back a sorted array of type `[Loto]`

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Thanks, it helped me.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are not ordered. What you need is to convert it to array, and then sort it. So something like this.

```
let lotoArray = lotoDictionary.allObjects as [Loto]

lotoArray.sort { $0.hafta < $1.hafta }
```

Comment: This is exactly what Amin Negm-Awad suggested before you. Dictionaries by default are not sorted.

Comment: There’s no need to convert to an array first like this – you can sort `dict.values` directly.

Comment: That is true. But this way it is easier for the asker to understand what is going on.

Comment: @StefanSalatic that is true, but in this case, you can simply add an edit to the original answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The keys of a dictionary are not sorted. You can get an array of the values and sort that array.

Comment: Actually i tried this but i could not sort. May be i did something wrong. I'll check again.